# Red button experiment - quantify partially unknown, possibly infinite durations?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Imagine there is a red button and a population of people.
Two things are happening all the time:

1. A person sees the button (and automatically enters the experiment).
2. A person presses the button (or not).

The duration I'm interested in is the time $t \in (0, +\infty )$ between seeing and pressing the button.

---

Some questions naturally come to mind, such as:

- What is the percentage of people participating in the experiment who press the button?
- How long does it take (e.g. on average) to press the button?
- How/if is the time to press the button changing?

I've found it quite troublesome to reason about. There is no time limit, so after seeing the button a person can come back in a day, week, month, year, etc. and press it.
Because of that, I think it's reasonable to assume that everyone is bound to press the button, albeit after a potentially infinite amount of time.

But quantifying the durations ain't easy anyway. Following the same line of logic, there is a bunch of participants with unknown durations. Only the lower bounds can be inferred (because for them the button press can happen right now at the earliest).

Finally, participants from different periods cannot be compared directly. For example, trying to compare participants from 2021 vs 2011, the latter might have durations exceeding 10 years, which would wildly skew the distribution. Same (or equivalent) values in the "younger" group are still unknown.

---

Is there standard tooling or the area of mathematics formalising such problems?

Sincere apologies if the question sounds vague. For the sake of Q&A, we can single out a specific question, say, how to compensate for imbalanced durations while comparing participants from different periods?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be (implicitly) assuming that people live forever.  Practically (and, I would say, theoretically) a person can't "press the button after a potentially infinite amount of time".

Comment: @paw88789 In my opinion, whatever finite upper bound is proposed one could say that a person (maybe in a distant future) might live longer than that.